# Kali Linux doesn't detect my hard drive partitions

Tags: partition, kali-linux, mbr, grub-legacy

I wanted to install **Kali Linux** on my computer that is currently running windows 7 64bits, so I created a 200Gb free partition, made an installation USB key, and everything was running perfectly during the install until when I got to the point where I needed to choose the partition.  I chose "**manual**" but it says that all my hard drive is free and unpartitioned, and I can't format & repartition my HD since I have a lot of useful data that I can't backup externally.

PS : I'm running on a **mbr** partitionning system & **Legacy** Bios mode

Comment: what does `fdisk` show of that specific drive?

Comment: if i entered live mode it dos list my HD as free

Comment: I mean, please update your question to show what `fdisk` shows. I imagine your "created a 200Gb free partition" is labelled incorrectly which is why the installer is claiming it is in use.